# How I can hide a Button inside a Control Template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I set `Visibility="Visible"` for the **Button** inside the **Control Template** when the `IsSendBtnVisible` property in the code-behind is `true`?

Here's my **WPF** page:

```
<Page 
  x:Class="CardViewPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="CardViewPage">

   <Grid Name="content" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <DocumentViewer Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="documentViewer" />
   </Grid>

</Page>
```

Here's my **Custom Template** for the document viewer on this page:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
   ...
   <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
         ...
         <Button 
            Click="btnSendToServer_Click"  
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Visibility="Collapsed" />
         ...
      </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter>
   ...
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to declare [DependancyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) for ur DocumentViewer and use `TemplateBinding` in xaml ControlTemplate (`UrProperty` for example)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
          ...
          <Button Click="btnSendToServer_Click"  
                  Width="25"
                  Height="25"
                  Visibility="{TemplateBinding UrProperty}"
                  />
          ...
      </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: DocumentViewer is standart wpf component. How can i declare DependencyProperty inside him? I have property inside page code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use data triggers to achieve this...

```
<Button
 Click="btnSendToServer_Click"  
                  Width="25"
                  Height="25">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSendBtnVisible}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Make sure to set visibility to collapsed in the style but not in the button properties..

Note: Binding for data trigger may change depending on your data context

Answer (score 0):

Dima Martovoi,bathineni - thanks for replies.

Dima Martovoi, i think inherit from DocumentViewer is to hard for this small problem.
I tried to use variant with DataTrigger from bathineni's solution, but it's not works. Don't know, why.
Problem was solved using next binding:

```
<Button
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page},Path=SendToServerVisiblity}">
</Button>
```

where

```
 public Visibility SendToServerVisiblity
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsOnlineMode)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

in page code-behind